# Launch interactive shell programmatically

Tags: linux, shell

I need to do a interactive shell programmatically (in Node.js, but any language will do). 
The most important is that I want to start a REPL of any language (node, ruby, erlang etc.) and be able to get autocompletion

```
pri\t
```

which I want to get output in stderr (for instance)

```
print()        println()         printf()
```

And because it's in language REPL `compgen` cannot be used.
I've tried many ways but it seems that it fails because shell can't be interactive while opened programmatically.
Launchin `/bin/sh -i` just yeilds errors like:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (XXXX): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I've heard that I can't start interactive shell without the terminal, but when doing SSH autocompletion does work which means it can be emulated in some way.

I'd appreciate Your help. I can't continue my work without finding a solution to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can emulate a terminal using a *pseudoterminal*.  This is how ssh does it.  There's a lot to using a *pseudoterminal* though and the SO answer box isn't big enough for all of it.  So check the man page for [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html).

Comment: Can I assume it's preinstalled on every linux system?

Comment: @KrzysztofWende According to the man page for ``forkpty``, it is not standard but it is present in libc5 and glibc2 so it would be safe to assume that it's present on any up to date linux system.

Comment: YES! Finally it works. Thank You!
When the question will be available for bounty I'll give You 50 rep points.
That's the first answer that actually worked.